# Start all web projects at once in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

In my solution i have four different web projects running on the embedded developer web-server on different ports. Two of them are web-service applications and two are websites. Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to start all of them when i start any one of them, because they are depend of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the root node in solution explorer, and goto properties, you'll see the the 'StartUp Projects' item in the menu under 'Common Properties'

You can set that to multiple-projects, and choose the ones you want from there.